# Equal populations in stat_summary_bin values in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a normally-distributed independent variable. I'd like to bin them and plot the dependent variable mean of each bin. I can do this for bins of equal width, but I'd like means of bins with equal numbers of observations.

I'm having trouble figuring out which function to use to calculate bin width. Or would it be better to figure out the breaks separately and give those as a list?

This generates the graph with the even bin widths

```
a <- rnorm(1000, sd = 200)
b <- runif(1000)
df <- data.frame(a, b)

ggplot(data = df, aes( x = a, y = b)) + geom_point(alpha = 0.1) +
  stat_summary_bin(fun.y = mean, binwidth = 5, geom = "point", color = "red")
```

so I think I need a function for binwidth? Or would it be better to use breaks instead of setting binwidth? If so not sure how to get breaks with even size populations between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to calculate quantiles of your variable (with the function `quantile()` and then use `breaks` as you suggested ?

Comment: That works, thank you! Used this:
```{r}
a <- rnorm(1000, sd = 200)
b <- runif(1000)
df <- data.frame(a, b)

ggplot(data = df, aes( x = a, y = b)) + geom_point(alpha = 0.1) +
  stat_summary_bin(fun.y = mean, breaks = quantile(a, probs = seq(0, 1, by = 0.05)), geom = "point", color = "red")
```